# Mod_Rewrite homepage strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When my users log in, one of my script appends `?member=logged` to the end of the url.

However this is causing problems on my homepage which is throwing up a `404 error` .

How can I redirect all requests to `/?member=logged` to `/` ?

I tried the following but it did not work for me

```
RewriteRule ^/?member=logged$ /$1 [L,R=301] [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect `http://example.com/?member=logged` to `http://example.com/` you can use the following `RewriteRules` .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?member=logged [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.com/? [L,R]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^member=logged$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://exmaple.com/? [L,R]
```